# Write equivalent code for in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, nstimer

In my app I have a following piece of code:

```
__weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;

_pingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                             repeats:YES
                                               block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer)

{
    __strong __typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;
    [strongSelf pingWithBlock:nil];
}];
```

this works perfectly in iOS 10+, but I need the app to support iOS 9 as well. So I needed to provide a method that would work for both.

I tried this:

```
__weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;

_pingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                             target:weakSelf
                                           selector:@selector(pingWithBlock:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
```

pingWithBlock method is defined in the same class, it's an instance method.

But this doesn't seem to work, meaning I get a bad memory access crash.

If anyone has any suggestions it will be highly appreciated.

EDIT: 
 thanks to @dgatwood explanations code below fixes the issue

```
- (void)autoPing
{
   _pingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:self.autoCheckInterval
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(pingWithBlock)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
}

-(void)pingWithBlock
{
    [self pingWithBlock:nil];
}
```

Comment: Where's your `pingWithBlock:` method? And define "doesn't work".

Comment: just updated my question

Comment: Don't edit your question with the answer. Post an actual answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of odd. NSTimer retains its target.  Maybe that doesn't happen in this case because of the `__weak`, but I thought it did anyway.  *shrugs*

Either way, this sounds like a multithreading race condition:

- Your timer isn't retaining the object, so it could go away at any time.
- Something else *is* retaining the object.
- The timer is scheduled in the runloop of the thread that was running when the timer was constructed.
- That something else disposes of the reference to the object in another thread.
- The timer fires in the first thread and the zeroing weak reference hasn't zeroed because the object is still halfway through destroying itself.
- A crash occurs.

The best fix is to let the timer retain the target object (by removing all the `weakSelf` stuff).  If the timer is a repeating timer, provide a method to allow the code that disposes of the enclosing object to cancel that timer, and be careful to always call it.

Comment: thank you, reading trough your explanation brought me to the correct implementation!

Comment: "Maybe that doesn't happen in this case because of the __weak" That's irrelevant. Weak and strong are semantics of the local variable in this function. It has nothing to do with how the argument is passed. Only a *value* is passed -- it has nothing to do with variables or ownership semantics.

Comment: I believe that to be the case as well, which is why the behavior makes no sense unless there's an ARC bug in the compiler, because NSTimer retains its object according to the doc.  Self is strongly retained by whatever called the current method on self (or else this code wouldn't be running), and the timer increases the retain count, which means it should be retained by the timer even after whatever else is retaining it stops doing so, so the retain count cannot possibly drop to 0 at any point in that process, unless I'm missing something very subtle.